# google warns "Unverified developer" for private site with spreadsheets API

Tags: google-oauth

I privately host a site for my family that uses the Google Spreadsheets API (readonly). I received an email from google looking to "Remove risky access to your data". My site is listed with a warning:

[image: Google warns about Unverified Developer]

I've gone through the verification process (filling out this form: https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) but got the response that if the site is used privately "you don't need to go through the verification process". They state this in their FAQ also: [OAuth Developer Verification Form FAQ](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7394288#what-scenarios).

However, the site still shows a warning in Google's security check-up. I can ignore this but I think other family members will be worried unnecessarily OR ignore future warnings about other apps assuming it's the family one they normally ignore.

Is there a way to verify myself as a developer of a private site or mark the access as trusted so the warning doesn't recur?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making my site public and going through the usual verification process.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but rather to flag that this is an issue my dilemma as well. Although I run time-based Google Script within an organization. I've contacted folks at the Google Cloud Platform and they have opened a case. However, here is something interesting I've stumbled across just now. Go to your Google account and do Security Checkup

[image: manage account settings]

After the checkup your screen might be showing something like this

[image]

Try clicking "Dismiss" to prevent Google from removing your app.

[image: click dismiss]

I'm just testing it myself and if in an hour (that's how long it usually takes Google to remove your own script from the list of self-authorized apps with access to account info) Google won't remove it, I guess it would work for me!

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out too, let me know how it goes for you. I think in the end I might just make a public page that everyone can see so I can claim it's not a private website and get authenticated.

Comment: Unfortunately a day later it still asks me for permission and I still have to click Advanced->Proceed (unsafe) - did it work for you?